# Magento 2.3 installation issue

Tags: php, mysql, magento2

I'm installing the Magento 2 it stuck on 0% installation and give the these exception.

> [2020-04-09 17:06:01] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
> view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist,
> query was: SELECT main_table.* FROM core_config_data AS main_table
> {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42):
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
> main_table.* FROM core_config_data AS main_table at
> C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php:110,
> PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not
> found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist at
> C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php:91)"}
> []

Comment: Please format you message correctly so that it is easier to read and can help people willing to help you.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve that error? Is this even related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear to get an idea.
If you are installing a fresh magento 2 so I think magento can not create tables in your database.